# Repair water damaged side of vanity

Tags: water-damage

I have 2 cabinets to repair, both were damaged by water.

One, I need to replace the wood at the kickspace.  It is about 1/4 inch thick.

The other cabinets had had enough water to damage the veneer on the side, but not the underlying wood.  Is there a think veneer I can glue to the side of the cabinet (there is enough trim to hide the installation that is 1/4 inch or so)

If these products exist where can I find them?   I have been searching online with no luck.

[image]

Comment: A simple search showed many places to buy veneer.

Comment: Are you sure the underlying wood is good? Usually when veneer is damaged like that it's because the cabinet's made of particle board which collapses when exposed to water/moisture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with this water damage](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/107689/how-to-deal-with-this-water-damage)